# Javascript Second for loop never executes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that hides or shows an element after a number of seconds have elapsed. The elements are all give the class `.show-after-x-seconds` or `.hide-after-x-seconds` and an attribute called `data_seconds` with the number of seconds.

The first loop iterates through all the elements with that class but the second loop seems to be ignored. I tried switching their order and only the first loop executes.

```
<div class="hide-after-x-seconds" data_seconds="2">
    <img src="/static/img1.png">
</div>
<div class="show-after-x-seconds" style="display: none" data_seconds="4">
    <img src="/static/img2.png">
</div>

var show_these = $('.show-after-x-seconds');
for(var show in show_these) {
    show_this(show_these[show], parseInt(show_these[show].attributes.data_seconds.value));
}
var hide_these = $('.hide-after-x-seconds');
for(var hide in hide_these) {
    hide_this(hide_these[hide], parseInt(hide_these[hide].attributes.data_seconds.value));
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function hide_this(element_to_hide, x){
    sleep(x *1000).then(() => {
        element_to_hide.style.display = 'none';
    })
}
function show_this(element_to_show, x){
    sleep(x *1000).then(() => {
        element_to_show.style.display = 'block';
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you what you're doing wrong:

```
var hide_these = $('.hide-after-x-seconds');
for(var hide in hide_these) {
    console.log(hide_these[hide]);
}
```

You want to do

```
$('.hide-after-x-seconds').each(function() {
   hide_this(this,this.getAttribute('data-seconds'));
});
```

Also, change your attribute `data_seconds` to `data-seconds`. It'll still work, but `data_seconds` is a non-standard attribute. You'll want to use HTML5 [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Can you explain why only one loop was working before?

Comment: There's a dramatic difference for `for var...in` and jQuery's `each` method on a jQuery object. for var...in on a jQuery object loops over the properties of the jQuery object, `.each` loops over the nodes in the jQuery object.....all that, and if you opened your console you'd see a JavaScript error. The first loop never actually worked, it just appeared to work because the first property of the jQuery object returned by for `for var in` loop just so luckily happened to be the DOM node you wanted to show, the loop died on the second iteration and caused a script error.